# How to enter large functions in pdetool of MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working with pdetool of MATLAB for solving certain parabolic pde.
As you know there are prescribed format in pdetool for example in the parabolic case we have
$$du^{'}+{\rm div}(c*{\rm grad}(u))+a*u=f$$
where the values of $d,c,a,f$ should be specified.

My question is that can we enter $f$ or other parameters as a MATLAB function?

for example Dirac delta or anything else.

Thanks a lot for your kind attention.

Comment: in the field for $f$ you should be able to enter a mathematical function (for example sin(x).*cos(y))

Comment: I know, but I want to include more complex function that is programmed as m file

Comment: You can do that too. Check out the example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you define a function $f(x,y) = y^2\tan(x)$ via

```
function fcn = fcn(x,y)

fcn = tan(x).*y.^2;

end
```

then when you solve the PDE, define $x$ and $y$ as symbolic variables, and do the following:

```
syms x y

c = 1;

a = 'x.*y'; % for example

f = 'fcn(x,y)';

d = 1;

u = parabolic(u0,tlist,model,c,a,f,d);
```

Comment: @All You are very welcome!